# Changing the context of a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is taken from John Resig`s Learning Advanced Javascript #25, called changing the context of a function.

1) in the line `fn() == this` what does this refer to? is it referring to the this inside the function where it says return this?

2) although I understand the purpose of the last line (to attach the function to a specific object), I don't understand how the code does that.  Is the word "call" a pre-defined JavaScript function? In plain language, please explain "fn.call(object)," and explicitly tell me whether the object in parens `(object)` is the same object as the `var object`.

3). After the function has been assigned to the object, would you call that function by writing `object.fn();` ?

```
var object = {}; 
function fn(){ 
  return this; 
} 
assert( fn() == this, "The context is the global object." ); 
assert( fn.call(object) == object, "The context is changed to a specific object."
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is a function defined for a `Function` object. The first parameter to `call` is the object that `this` refers to inside the function being called.

When `fn()` is called without any particular context, `this` refers to the global context, or the `window` object in browser environments. Same rules apply for the value of `this` in the global scope. So in `fn() == this)`, `this` refers to the global object as well. However, when it is called in the context of some other object, as in `fn.call(object)`, then `this` inside `fn` refers to `object`.

`fn.call(object)` does not modify or assign anything to `object` at all. The only thing affected is the `this` value inside `fn` only for the duration of that call. So even after this call, you would continue calling `fn()` as regular, and not as `object.fn()`.

The example simply demonstrates that the `this` value inside a function is dynamic.

Comment: regarding the first paragraph in your answer (i.e. call and object), is that always the case or just with this specific code? thank you very much for your help.

Comment: When a function is invoked with `call` or `apply`, the first parameter will always determines the `this` value inside that function. That is always the case