# How does JavaScript assign context to this of event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*After reading related questions [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334611/changing-the-context-of-a-function-in-javascript) , [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536164/changing-context-of-a-function-in-javascript?rq=1)
I still haven't found an answer to the following question:*

Javascript can set context (i.e. set `this`) with:  `bind` , `call` and `apply`.

But when I'm write an event handler:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').onclick = function ()
                                                   {
                                                      alert(this.value)
                                                   }
```

*Who/What* actually *attaches* `this` to the `object` itself ?

P.S. When using jQuery's  :

```
  $("#myInput").bind(function (){...})
```

there *is* an internal implementation of  (`bind`, `call` or `apply`)

So when I am **not** using jQuery, who is doing it?

Comment: The DOM implementation is responsible for that IMO

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click

Comment: @wroniasty can you reference me where is says there something about context&this ? in the table the context talks about the properties inside...

Comment: @wroniasty, you took my words right out of my mouth, this is basically yet another "by definition" answer

Comment: Your #1 and #2 both link to the same question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why, the DOM/JavaScript of course, it's supposed to work that way by W3C.

> Event handlers are invoked in the *context* of a particular object (the current event target) and are provided with the event object itself.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#glossary-event-handler)

How exactly that happens, we don't know. It's an implementation detail.

All we know is, that the semantics as defined by the W3C are achieved in *some way*, but which part of the browser does that and and how, that is left up to the browser developers, and they can implement it as they see fit.

Comment: We do know how this happens. It's how JavaScript is designed to work.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall [misread, read don't]: No, we don't. We know *what* happens, not *how*. That's a difference.

Comment: Actually we don't know how the DOM implm calls the handler. Nor should we care about it.

Comment: @phant0m Sorry, I read that as if we don't know how JavaScript treats contexts, not how the DOM implementation works. My bad :)

Comment: _Event handlers are invoked in the context of a particular object_ but so does regular functions ( which uses[this] inside them) so what's the difference ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir You need to distinguish between *what* happens, and *how* something happens. Surely, you will agree that if you put a (compatible) pan on a stove and turn it on, it gets hot. We have now come to an understanding about *what* happens: It gets hot. However, the *how* has not been addressed. There are some, that use gas, you can run them on wood if you're old fashioned, you can use electric stoves, or you can use the new fancy induction-based stoves. The methods used are all very different, but the result is the same.

Comment: ok... But from 30,000 feet does event handler methods are different than normal methods ? i'll be glad to get also a 30,000 feet answer (not internally how the oven gets hot - but in general why is this overn gets hot in a XXX way , while the othere gets hot in YYY way )

Comment: The difference is, that the quote I provided only tells you *what* happens in the case of an `onclick` event. On the other hand, the JavaScript specification tells you *what* happens when you execute `x.f()`. But they both do not tell you *how* that happens. What you are doing is mixing the two up. You see something (the `x.f()` part), that specifies *one* case where a function is run in a certain context. Now, you're assuming that this mechanism is the how of how the event handler is implemented. -- Both things are *whats*, the second is not necessarily the *how* to the first *what*.

Comment: So youre saying `x.f()` is known (how and what)  and event handlers knonw as `what` but we dont know `how`.....right ?

Comment: No, I'm saying we don't know *how* `x.f()` works either. But we know *what* happens: The function `x.f` gets called, and `x` serves as context for that function call. Do you know *how* that works? I don't. I only know *what* happens on a conceptual level. *hoping SO tells me to discuss this further in chat*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17548/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-phant0m)

Answer (score 2):

To sum up all the discussions:

- In general it is JavaScript that binds `this` to `o` inside a function call, when `o.x()` is called.
- However, there are some alternative methods of calling functions (like `f.apply()` and `f.call()`) that change this behaviour.
- `onclick` is a special case, and the method used to invoke it is unknown and depends on the DOM implementation.

Comment: why the onclick is special case ? its just a method... please correct me

Comment: it's a special case because it's called by the DOM. It's context may be bound to its call via many methods (`element.call.onclick()`, `element.onclick()` etc.), and it may vary between DOM implementations.

Comment: So just because the same Onclick can be called by different objects (**without** using apply/bind/call)- it is different ?

Comment: No, not by different objects. At some point, the browser gets notified, that the mouse has been clicked at some place. It then somehow evaluates which element was "hit". It then places a call *somehow* to its onclick handler, if existent. However, in what fashion this is called, we don't know. There's no telling whether the JavaScript interpreter effectively gets code in the fashion of `element.onclick()` to execute, or whether the browser has some other more optimized, special-case way to do this.

Comment: @RoyiNamir The thing is, that nobody can answer this with certitude, unless he wrote that part of the browser. But because there is not just one browser, you may get multiple very different, but all correct answers. That's why wroniasty and I are trying to stress, that there is no specific answer to this question, but rather accept that it happens according to the specification, in *some unknown way*.

Comment: Sorry , But isnt 3'rd point is like the 1'st point ? `o.onclick()` so its `o` who supply the context ?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, of an `onclick` handler it's perfectly straight forward: a DOM element *is* an object, you're defining the `onclick` property to be a function. That function effectively becomes a method of that DOMElement/object.
When that object is clicked, the function is called as a method of that element, so this points to its *owner*, the element.

Put simply, the context in which the function executes is the same as the context in which is was created (again: in your example as a method of a DOM Element), unless a reference to a function *object* is assigned to another object, or when that function *object* is invoked in another context using `call` or `apply` & co.
There's a little more to it than this, of course: as I hinted at above, functions are objects themselves and are said to be *loosely* coupled to their *"owner"*. Well, actually they don't have an owner as such, each time a function is called, its context is determined:

```
var foo = someObject.someFunction;//reference to method
someObject.someFunction();//this === someObject, context is the object preceding the function
foo();//implies [window].foo(); ==> this is window, except for strict mode
```

As @wroniasty pointed out, my talking about *ownership* might be slightly confusing. The thing is, functions are objects, they're not owned by anything. When an object is assigned a method, all that object really *owns* is a reference to a given function object. When that function is called via that reference, `this` will point to the object that owned the calling reference. 
When we apply that to your `elem.onclick = function(){}`, we see the element only *owns* a reference to a function expression that was declared in some scope (global, namespace-object, doesn't matter). When the click event fired, that *reference* will be used to call the handler, thus assigning a reference to the element to `this`. To clarify:

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = (function()
{//This function returns the actual handler
    var that = this;//closure var
    console.log(this);//logs window object
    //defined in global context
    return function(e)//actual handler
    {
        console.log(this === that);//false
        console.log(this);//elem
        console.log(that);//window
    };
})();//IIFE
```

So the handler was declared in the global context, and the handler can access its the context it was declared in using `that`, thanks to closures (but that's another story). The point is, the event references the handler using the `onclick` property of the element `foo`. That property is a reference to a function object, so the function object sets its context to whatever object made the call.

I do hope this clears up any confusion I caused with regard to *ownership* of functions, and perhaps how context in JS is determined.

Comment: An anonymous function has no "owner"

Comment: @wroniasty: would `this` not refer to the window or document or wich ever context it is running in? Even an anonymous function must run under some context, would it not?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes, every function runs under some context as far as I know. But if you use the term "owner", then a function can have multiple owners. As such, the term "owner" is not very good, because it's an ad-hoc relationship, not something intrinsic to the function (Which Elias explained quite well).

Comment: @phant0m: I see. Thank you for explaining this. I'm still myself learning about the finer points of JavaScript, closures and context, etc. So still getting a little confused now and then.

Comment: @wroniasty: in case of an anon. function `this` doesn't _"inherit"_ the context from its outer scope, if it did, you wouldn't need to declare a `that` or `_self` var every now and then. every function is called in a global context, unless it's explicitly been declared as a method and called as one _OR_ it's been bound (`bind`), `call`-ed or applied (`apply`) explicitly. As far as ownership goes: functions never _Really_ have an owner, that's why I said they're loosely bound and are stand-alone. It can help to think in terms of ownership at first. Maybe I should clarify that bit

Comment: @wroniasty: I just noticed: when I said every function is called in a global context, what I meant to say was _"every function is defined in a global context_, but not always referenced globally...

Answer (score 1):

The answers saying it is the DOM are wrong.

This is part of JavaScript itself, as a language. The DOM is ONLY what the name indicates "Document Object Model", which is just how HTML is represented for manipulation by using JavaScript. Objects related to the DOM follow the behavior specified by the standards, but this is implemented by using JS for it. It is the JS engine what does this, in communication with whatever layout engine is being used (Gecko, Trident, WebKit, Presto, etc.). So, if WebKit detects an event, it passes it to the JS engine as the DOM specification indicates so that it can manipulated by the JS programmer (which is why you're even asking about this, because you can work with it).

In other words, if you're writing something in JavaScript, the only engine that understands how to read and execute that is the JS engine. This engine (v8, SpiderMonkey/Jugger/Trace) will receive data from the layout engine and use it so that you can interact with it. Similarly, on the other hand, whenever you run code that affects the layout, the changes will be detected by the layout engine and it will change the layout so that the user perceives the changes: even if the JS code might have initiated this, it is the layout engine that takes care of the layout.

What "this" is when you assign a function to an object, is simply wherever the function belongs to. So, if you assign a function to instance of object a, then said function will refer to a whenever you use "this" inside of it.

If you wanted to think of it in implementation terms, think of it this way:
Whenever you are calling a method, you do so by first telling an instance that you want to call a method with N parameters. This instance calls the method but adds itself into the context, as "this".

In Python this is done more explicitly by making the first parameter of all instance methods the instance itself. Here it is the same, but the instance is passed implicitly instead of explicitly.

Remember, the instance owns the method. When you do "document.getElementById('something')" the call returns an object (which happens to be an HTMLElement object that is part of the DOM, but that's coincidental to how JS interacts with the DOM), and then you are assigning the function as the property click.

Then, whenever you call the method, the JavaScript engine passes the instance by default, just like it passes other variables (like arguments is also generated without you doing anything, also done by the JS engine which implements the ECMAScript standard).

I would recommend checking pages 63:

"The this keyword evaluates to the value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context."

but most importantly, page 68 "Function calls"

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: This assumes the browser actually evaluates JavaScript code in the likes of: `element.onclick()`, this is an unfounded assumption. There is no *need* for the browser to do that.

Comment: DOM is also responsible for handling click events i.e. calling the handlers.

Comment: The DOM you use is a JavaScript implementation of it. The matter of what "this" is, is a matter of JavaScript. You can use the DOM on other languages too if you wanted, and depending on the language, "this" might not even exist.

Comment: No it's not. It's the DOM implementation that either does `element.onclick()` or `element.onclick.apply(context)` or something equivalent. In the first case `this` becomes `element` in the latter it becomes `context`.

Answer (score 0):

This really has nothing to do with the DOM as has been mentioned, but how JavaScript is designed to work when you call a function within an object.

Take this as an example:

```
var myObject = {
    id: 1,
    onclick: null
}

myObject.onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.id);
}
```

Calling `myObject.onclick()` will log `1` to the console, which means `myObject` is its context.

Since `onclick` is also a property of an object, `this` will be the parent object, in your case an `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Who then tells JavaScript that a click event has happened on a specific element?

Comment: The DOM implementation in the browser. This however, is now what he was asking.

Comment: He's asking `Who/What actually attaches this to the object`, not how javascript works.

Comment: The thing is, that we can't make the assumption that the browser actually places a call to `element.onclick()` (in the very literal sense, i.e. that code being eval'ed), but there may be some optimized mechanism that achieves this directly. This is why I said, "it's an implementation detail". We have *no* guarantees in the specification that this is what it does, and as wroniasty said: "nor should we care about it", because we only care about the semantics, not about the implementation.

Comment: @wroniasty I can read. No need to repost his question here. It has everything to do with how JavaScript works.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall so what you are saying is that when a click event occurs, what actually happens is `element.onclick()`??

Comment: @phant0m That's the reason I am not talking about the DOM implementation (which I also mention in my answer) since it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @wroniasty Stop putting words in my mouth. My answer is based on my interpretation of his question, and I repeat myself: the DOM implementation is irrelevant

Comment: In that case, you're only answering what `this` is inside `f` when you call `x.f()`, but it's not (necessarily) related to the question.

Comment: @phant0m That's your interpretation of his question. Not mine.

Comment: How do you mean? (I'll delete that afterwards so this doesn't get too long, just edit it into the previous comment)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall didn't mean to put anything in your mouth. I'm just saying that the `onclick` method, which OP was asking about is a special case, and may not be as simple as `x.f()`

Comment: Guys , Fu** my question , please dont fight and lets find the right answer. stick to JS . :-) and thanks for trying to solve this misunderstanding of myne

Comment: NO! This has gone too far to stop now!! Just kidding. Sorry @MarcusEkwall, I didn't mean to offend you.

Answer (score 0):

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-3-this/#this-value-in-the-function-code

Basically, it's done by JavaScript internals.

The context is the object calling the function, e.g.

```
elem.onclick();  // elem === this
```

However:

```
func = elem.onclick;
func() // global === this
```

Answer (score 0):

For illustration purposes, although implementations may differ, think of the following function

```
 function f() { alert(this.name); }
```

as

```
function f(this) { alert(this.name); }
```

Imagine **this** as a secret parameter that you can override with bind, apply and call but that normally gets set to the calling object by the browser.

Example

```
var a = {},
    b = {};

a.name = "John";
b.name = "Tom";

// "this" param added secretly
function printName( ) { 
    console.log( this.name ) 
};

a.printName = printName     
b.printName = printName;
```

When calling the printName function the browser sets that "secret" **this** parameter to the calling function. In the example below this is b and so "Tom" is printed to the console.

```
printName( ); // global context assumed so this === window
b.printName( ); // this === b and outputs "Tom"
printName.call( a ); //this === a and outputs "John"
```

Further info [here](http://devign.me/javascript-this-keyword/).

Comment: the _function f(this)_ is nice and refreshing site , but where the execution like `f(myObj)` is made ?